# c++ combine multiple std::find & std::find reverse starting in the middle of the vector

Tags: c++, std

Im having trouble to find some elements the most speedy way.

Given the two vectors I want to start searching elements starting at a previously given position (3), and compare them to another vector. Because i know the "valid" values are 99% around the starting point im trying to build a mechanism, that has 4 steps:

```
Valid positions are: vec1[i] == 1 && vec2[i] != vec1[5]

vec1 : 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, (3), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1
vec2 : 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, (0), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0
1:              ^======S                           fail: vec1[5] == vec2[3]
2:                     S==================^        fail: vec1[5] == vec2[11]
3:     ^========S                                  fail: vec1[5] == vec2[0]
4:                                        S=====^  good: vec1[5] != vec2[13]
```

I tried to implement this with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec1 = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};
    std::vector<int> vec2 = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};

    auto down1 = std::find(vec1.rbegin() + 5, vec1.rend(), 1);
    //first search down for first element
    if (down1 != vec1.rend() && vec2[5] != vec1[std::distance(down1, vec1.rend()) - 1])
    {
        std::cout << "First downsearch: '1' found and Vec2[" << std::distance(down1, vec1.rend()) - 1 << "] is not the same as Vec1[5]" << std::endl;
        // in loop I do continue; here
    }

    auto up1 = std::find(vec1.begin() + 5, vec1.end(), 1);
    if (up1 != vec1.end() && vec2[5] != up1 - vec1.begin())
    {
        std::cout << "First upsearch: '1' found and Vec2[" << up1 - vec1.begin() << "] is not the same as Vec1[5]" << std::endl;
        // in loop I do continue; here
    }

    //second search down, starting at down1 <<<--- not working
    auto down2 = std::find(down1, vec1.rend(), 1);
    if (down2 != vec1.rend() && vec2[5] != vec1[std::distance(down2, vec1.rend()) - 1])
    {
        std::cout << "Second downsearch: First '1' found and Vec2[" << std::distance(down2, vec1.rend()) - 1 << "] is not the same as Vec1[5]" << std::endl;
        // in loop I do continue; here
    }

    return 1;
}
```

But I think i fail with using the first down iterator for the second down search..

Note: The Element I’m trying to find for can occur at maximum two times. One time it fits the condition, one time it does not.

Do you have any ideas? Thank you!! :-)

Right now I’m using just a while loop to incrementely search one below, then one up, two below, two up.. I assumed std::find would be a better solution, because sometimes the values are very far away. (1%)

Comment: Please don't add "edit" sections to your question. Edit it to improve it, so it contains all info in one consistent question. That said, please extract and provide a [mcve] and also add what you expected and what you got. Point is, "I think i fail" is completely useless to convey why you think something failed.

Comment: What do the values in the vectors represent? Perhaps there's a better way of organizing them even before doing this search?

Comment: Sorry for the edits and the bad formulation, I’m trying to solve this for hours now and my head 404. Rearranging the problem is sadly not possible. My main problem is, that I don’t know how to start a search from Index i in a vector down, then check, then search up, then check and then search down starting at the point where I the first search down ended. (Down I mean reverse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code is a bit confusing because in the condition you compare to `vec2[5]` but in the message you say `Vec1[5]`.

Second, I'm not really sure why do you use `std::distance` instead of just de-referencing the iterator:

```cpp
if (down1 != vec1.rend() && vec2[5] != *down1)
```

And finally, your last `std::find` doesn't work as you expected because you start at `down1`, which already points to the searched value. You want to start searching from the next element:

```cpp
auto down2 = std::find(down1+1, vec1.rend(), 1);
```

But be careful, `down1` may be `rend` at this point so you should check for that first.

Comment: Hey danadam, thank you for your answer! You solved my problem =) I have one more question and maybe you can help me again: What if down1 should not end at rend but at another specific position, that i know the index from? For an non-reverse iterator I could use &vec1[i], how about at the reverse-iterator?

Thank you!!

Comment: `&vec1[i]` will give you the address of i-th element, not the iterator. To get the iterator you simply advance `begin()` (or `rbegin()`) by `i`. Either `auto myend = vec1.begin() + i;` or more generic `auto myend = vec1.begin(); std::advance(myend, i);`